# Typescript and node_modules in Docker failing to find types

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm, node-modules

I am having issues with building-in node_modules to a Docker image and other related answers did not work for me. I built-in node_modules to the image because filesystem interaction is slow in containers and the host OS (my computer) is different than the guest OS (image/container), so if I just copied node_modules from host to guest during image build - or mounted my host node_modules as a volume to the subsequent container - my application would break in the container due to platform-specific dependencies (omitted for brevity).

My approach is simple. When building the image:

- Copy my NPM package's source code from host to guest
- `npm install` on the guest to build-in node_modules
- Configure the image so that when a container runs, Typescript will compile our source (mounted as a volume) using a different tsconfig which tells it to look elsewhere for Node types (in the node_modules we built-in).

I then run a container from the image and mount my host NPM package's source code as a volume (this approach gives me the ability to live-edit the source on my host and see the changes reflected in the guest OS).

Issue 1: In a container, Typescript can not find type definition files for Node and fails to compile:

```
% npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx /opt/app_cache/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.container.json

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions
```

Issue 2: In a container, npx does not work to find tsc, probably due to node_modules being "built-in". How do I tell npx to look elsewhere? I tried NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX etc but nothing seemed to work. For example, on my host OS, this works:

```
% npm install
% npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.container.json
```

In the container, this fails because npx is not finding typescript and is instead installing the `tsc` package:

```
% npm install 
% npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.container.json

This is not the tsc command you are looking for
```

...so I had to be explicit about where tsc is to get it to work:

```
%  npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx /opt/app_cache/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.container.json
```

Example commands:

```
cd so
npm install
npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.json # OK!
rm -rf node_modules

docker pull ubuntu:20.04
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f ./dockerfile.development -t so:latest .
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/:/opt/app/:rw -e GENERATE_UNIQUE=false so:latest # Error!
```

Files (I kept the structure since it could have something to do with the problem?):

```
user so % tree
.
├── config
│   ├── tsconfig.base.json
│   ├── tsconfig.website.container.json
│   └── tsconfig.website.json
├── dockerfile.development
├── dockerfile.development.dockerignore
├── dockerfile.development.entrypoint.sh
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "so",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "so ?",
    "private": false,
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "18.7.17",
        "cross-env": "5.2.1",
        "ts-node": "10.9.1",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
// This file is responsible for nothing. It is a stub!
// VS Code requires a Typescript config file in the root folder of this source 
//  and can not be configured otherwise (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463). 
// All app source config is in the ./config folder; go there!
{
    "extends": "./config/tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

config/tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2019",
        "module": "es2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["es2022", "dom", "dom.iterable", "webworker"],
        "types": ["node"],
        
        "skipLibCheck": true, // Needed to skip node_modules imports from being included.
        
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

        // Typescript development rules:
        "strict": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "exclude": ["../node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

config/tsconfig.website.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "rootDir": "../src"
    },
    "include": ["../src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

config/tsconfig.website.container.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../dist",
        "rootDir": "../src",
        // Tell Typescript to look elsewhere for type defs since we build-in node_modules to the container.
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "paths": {
            "*": [ "/opt/app_cache/node_modules/*" ],
        }
    },
    "include": ["../src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

src/test.ts:

```
console.log('test');

import * as fs from 'fs';

const somethingWithNode = (filePath: string, data: Buffer) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data);
}

somethingWithNode('/tmp/test', Buffer.from('test'));
```

dockerfile.development:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV NODE_ENV="development"

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
curl \
gnupg \
build-essential && \
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
apt-get remove -y --purge cmdtest && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y nodejs && \
node -v && npm -v

RUN mkdir -p /opt/node_modules_cache/node_modules 
RUN npm config set yes true

RUN mkdir /opt/app_cache && mkdir /opt/app
COPY . /opt/app_cache/
RUN cd /opt/app_cache && npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/dockerfile.development.entrypoint.sh"]
```

dockerfile.development.dockerignore:

```
# Ignore OS files. 
.DS_Store

# Ignore dependency files.
node_modules/
package-lock.json

# Ignore built src.
dist/
```

dockerfile.development.entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

ls -al /opt/app_cache/node_modules

echo $NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX
echo $NODE_PATH
echo $PATH

cd /opt/app

node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules --no-warnings --loader /opt/app_cache/node_modules/ts-node/esm ./src/test.ts
npx cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx /opt/app_cache/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --project ./config/tsconfig.website.container.json
```